# Set attribute in checkbox on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, replace

how can an HTML element/tag for example this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1234"  checked onClick="replace(1234)"> I have a car<br>
```

replaced with this when clicked

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1234" unchecked onClick="replace(1234)"> I have a car<br>
```

I want to replace only the input tag and change HTML code in tha position

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `unchecked` isn't a valid HTML attribute. You also don't need to replace the whole element, you simply need to read the `checked` property of the element

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#1234').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).attr('checked',true);
      console.log('checked')
    }
    else {
      $(this).attr('checked',false);
      console.log('unchecked')
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="1234"  checked > I have a car<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly check the above snippet. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the element has the attribute `checked`, if so then it will remove it and set a new attribute called `unchecked`

```js
function replace(id) {
  var attr = $("#" + id).attr('checked');
  // For some browsers, `attr` is undefined; for others,
  // `attr` is false.  Check for both.
  if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    $("#" + id).removeAttr('checked').attr("unchecked", "")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="1234" checked onClick="replace(1234)"> I have a car<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code. It will help you:

```
$('#1234').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(this).attr('checked',true);
    else
      $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Comment: yes that was type mistake thanks for notice that one

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call checkbox click event as shown in below code

```js
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chk']", function() {
  //alert(this.id);
  debugger;

  var ischecked2 = $(this).is(':checked');

  if (ischecked2) { //checked
    console.log("checked");
  } else { //unchecked
    console.log("unchecked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js">
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="1234" name="chk"> I have a car<br>
```